# What is the meaning of あまり in this dialogue?

Tags: translation, meaning

Is doesn't seem to be "not very much"...

> A: 運転ができますか
>
> B: **あまり**、うまくはないですけど

I would be grateful if someone could help. :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This あまり does mean "(not) very" or "(not) really", as found in [these examples](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=amari-2).

あまりうまくはないですけど literally means "Although I'm not *very* good (at driving)", which already implies "Yes I can drive" without actually saying it.